# C - How to initialize a memory space to 0x00, before allocating it to an array

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am trying to make an ssd1306 library for learning stm32, for which I've made an `*init[]` array. All of the defines and macros return `uint8_t`. The idea behind this was that I'll detect where NULL is in the memory and stop incrementing (the logical bug would be that this would fail if there were exactly 4,8,12,16... array elements in the rows, which is never the case). In this, I assumed that all the memory addresses allocated to the array would be initialized to 0x00 (obviously not), and I ran into a problem where a single random byte would corrupt everything. So, I was looking for a way to make all the memory locations 0x00. Feel free to suggest any new ways I could do the same thing.

I could declare `*init[]`, do `calloc`, and then initialize every sub-array individually, but that would make adding new init parameters that much more cumbersome. If all else fails, ill use it.

[image: Array memory locations]

[image: Memory view showing random bytes messing with it]

```
uint8_t *init[]= {
              (uint8_t[]){MUX_RATIO_ADDR, SET_MUX_RATIO(0X1F)},
              (uint8_t[]){DISPLAY_OFFSET_ADDR, SET_DISPLAY_OFFSET(0X00)},
              (uint8_t[]){DISPLAY_START_LINE(0)},
              (uint8_t[]){SEG_REMAP(0x00)},
              (uint8_t[]){SCAN_DIRECTION(0X00)},
              (uint8_t[]){COM_CONFIG_ADDR, COM_CONFIG(0X01)},
              (uint8_t[]){CONTRAST_CONTROL_ADDR, SET_CONTRAST(0X7F)},
              (uint8_t[]){VER_ADDR_MODE},
              (uint8_t[]){0X21, 0X3F, 0X7F},
              (uint8_t[]){0X22, 0X4, 0X7},
              (uint8_t[]){DISPLAY_ON(0)},
              (uint8_t[]){INVERSE_MODE(0)},
              (uint8_t[]){DISPLAY_CLK_DIVIDE_ADDR, DISPLAY_CLK_DIVIDE(1,8)},
              (uint8_t[]){0xdb, 0x40},
              (uint8_t[]){CHARGE_PUMP_ADDR, CHARG_PUMP_ON},
              (uint8_t[]){NORMAL_MODE(1)}
      };
      for (int i=0; i<sizeof(init)/sizeof(init[0]); i++) {
          for(int j=0; init[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
              HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, DEV_ADDR, COMMAND_MODE, 1, &init[i][j], 1, 50);
          }
      }
```

HAL function declaration for referance:

`HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Mem_Write (I2C_HandleTypeDef*, uint16_t , uint16_t , uint16_t, uint8_t*, uint16_t , uint32_t );`

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking.  What memory are you needing to set to zero?  Why not simply include the NUL sentinel in the initialisation? `(uint8_t[]){MUX_RATIO_ADDR, SET_MUX_RATIO(0X1F),0}, ...` or have a length element at the start `(uint8_t[]){2, MUX_RATIO_ADDR, SET_MUX_RATIO(0X1F)},...` ;

Comment: Do not store it in the RAM. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

> I'll detect where NULL is in the memory

What NULL? NULL is a macro for null pointer constants. Most likely with the value 0, but there are no null pointers anywhere in your code. No null terminated strings either.

> In this, I assumed that all the memory addresses allocated to the array would be initialized to 0x00 (obviously not)

In the code you posted, everything is data and initialized to the values you have provided. You have intentionally made it as compact as possible. For example `(uint8_t[]){0xdb, 0x40}` means "allocate 2 bytes and fill them with this data". There is no null termination like in strings, because these are 8 bit integers, not strings, plus you didn't allocate any room for one either. You only get implicit null termination when you initialize with string literals: `"like this"`.

Anyway, the whole code is nonsensical for a microcontroller program. This is a constant table, it should be `const` all over so that it ends up in flash, not in RAM. It's a huge waste of RAM memory. Compound literals `(uint8_t[]) { ... }`  also get allocated in RAM. Don't use them in an embedded system unless you know what they actually do.

The best fix to salvage this code is probably to do this:

```
static const uint8_t init[][4]= 
{
  {MUX_RATIO_ADDR, SET_MUX_RATIO(0X1F)},
  {DISPLAY_OFFSET_ADDR, SET_DISPLAY_OFFSET(0X00)}
  ...
};
```

Now the code is in flash and there's explicitly at least one zero at the end of each 1D array, because they are at most 3 bytes long. Array initialization is guaranteed to fill up spare bytes that weren't set with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, if just a single array would be ok. This way, you would also save all the uint8_t pointers, you just need an additional byte instead.

```
static const uint8_t ssd1306_init[] = {
// len, data
   2, MUX_RATIO_ADDR, SET_MUX_RATIO(0X1F),
   2, DISPLAY_OFFSET_ADDR, SET_DISPLAY_OFFSET(0X00),
   1, DISPLAY_START_LINE(0),
   1, SEG_REMAP(0x00),
   1, SCAN_DIRECTION(0X00),
   2, COM_CONFIG_ADDR, COM_CONFIG(0X01),
   2, CONTRAST_CONTROL_ADDR, SET_CONTRAST(0X7F),
   1, VER_ADDR_MODE,
   3, 0X21, 0X3F, 0X7F,
   3, 0X22, 0X4, 0X7,
   1, DISPLAY_ON(0),
   1, INVERSE_MODE(0),
   2, DISPLAY_CLK_DIVIDE_ADDR, DISPLAY_CLK_DIVIDE(1,8),
   2, 0xdb, 0x40,
   2, CHARGE_PUMP_ADDR, CHARG_PUMP_ON,
   1, NORMAL_MODE(1),
};
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(init)/sizeof(init[0]); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < init[i]; j++)
    {
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, DEV_ADDR, COMMAND_MODE, 1, &init[i+1+j], 1, 50);
    }
    i += j; // advance i by number bytes transmitted 
}
```

On the other side, when I look at your I2C Write function, it looks like you write one byte at a time anyway, no matter if a CMD, a ADDR/DATA pair or just a value triple. Why then the split into arrays and check for '\0' at all? If it works (*), my example would not even need the additional 1st byte for length. Just write the commands in an array of bytes, and send the array out:

```
static const uint8_t ssd1306_init[] = {
    MUX_RATIO_ADDR, SET_MUX_RATIO(0X1F),
    DISPLAY_OFFSET_ADDR, SET_DISPLAY_OFFSET(0X00),
    ...
}
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(init)/sizeof(init[0]); i++)
{
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, DEV_ADDR, COMMAND_MODE, 1, &init[i], 1, 50);
}
```

(*) This "if it works" is about, if the device accepts it this way. I also wonder, if the HAL function would accept a certain number of bytes and does a burst transfer or such.
In that case, you might even use a DMA driven transfer.
But for this, you should consult the device and the HAL documentation more closely.